# Corona sdk: read a file

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I recently started working on corona sdk and am trying to read a file and print it line by line. I searched for codes everywhere but they didn't work... It's important as I'm on an internship and need to get it done as soon as possible.

Here's the code that I used:

```
local path = system.pathForFile( "Level File Structure.txt", system. ResourceDirectory  )
local file = io.open( path, "r" )

for line in file:lines() do
  print( line )
end
io.close( file )
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work provided the file exists and the path is correct;

```
local path = "Level File Structure.txt", system.ResourceDirectory

local function printWords()
    local file = io.open(path, "r")
    for lines in file:lines() do
        print (lines)
    end
    io.close(file)
end
printWords()
```

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to look at [this blog](http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2012/02/14/reading-and-writing-files-in-corona/) which describes how to both read and write the files.

Comment: Thanks a lot... I figured it out! Actually I sought for the output at the wrong place!